# How to make an rdd from netcdf file using Spark?

Tags: scala

we  are reading a file like SaprkContext.textfile("filepath) in normal case .
But how to make one rdd from netcdf file ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a NASA's project for working with scientific data (such as NetCDF) on Spark, called SciSpark https://scispark.jpl.nasa.gov/technology.html

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely familiar with netcdf file format, but what you could do is write a UDF and import the netcdf java library for opening and reading the data, format it into a structure which spark can load from (e.g. json, cvs, textfile) and then go on to load it from that format ...

Comment: Actualy i want to take a netcdf file like sparkContext.netcdffile(filepath).

Comment: This wont be possible unless you decide to modify the spark source code and issue a pull request for handling the new data format, and it gets accepted in an upcoming release. - here is a list of the valid API calls for 1.5.2 https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Comment: by spark try to load as hadoop file and you need to write custom input format for this.